How to integrate Razorpay in civicrm?
I want to integrate the Razor pay in civicrm.so how to integrate the Razor pay in civicrm.

To integrate Razorpay in civicrm use the below extensions
https://civicrm.org/extensions/razorpay-payment-processor

I think the Omnipay one does also support Razorpay
https://civicrm.org/extensions/omnipay-multiprocessor-extension
